# Levels for netcdf files in brick, R

Tags: time, raster, levels, ncdf4

I have many `.nc` files with a variable `"skt"`. 
What I want to do is to load all these files in R as raster brick and have apart from the variable, the time, too. 
I tried to do this with `levels`, but with no success. 
I would really appreciate any help.

```
list.files(pattern="*.nc")
list_all=list.files(pattern="*.nc")
skt_all<- brick(list_all,varname="skt",levels=4)


Warning messages:
1: In if (x == "" | x == ".") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!start %in% c("htt", "ftp")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (fileext %in% c(".GRD", ".GRI")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (!file.exists(x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if ((fileext %in% c(".HE5", ".NC", ".NCF", ".NC4", ".CDF", ".NCDF",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: you cannot provide multiple files to `brick`. Create several RasterBricks or use `stack` instead?

Comment: Hi @RobertHijmans. I assume that is because brick accepts onlly one level (is that correct?). In the case of stack though, can I have multiple levels? e.g. the variable I want and the time.

Comment: It is not directly related to ncdf and levels. You can simply only use one file, and you are providing multiple files.